# When I get a JSON object from PHP on iOS, I get the NULL value

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

FIRST EDIT:

I put returnData in JSONObjectWithData:options:error but the error persists.

The problem happens 1 in 10 times, but it's annoying because the application does not work.

```
2014-02-18 10:26:03.236 finalAbogados[47279:f803] Error en consulta basica: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x686c330 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

---

im doing an APP on iOS that get a JSON object from a PHP Script.

The script calls data from data base in MS SQL and encode these data in a JSON Object. Then i get the object on iOS and i use NSJSONSerialize for handle data.

**The problem is**, sometimes I get a null value and sometimes I get the array correctly. The data returned me the script is always the same, expose here:

```
[{"0":"","NombreOrganismo":"","1":"Judicial","NombreTipoInstancia":"Judicial","2":"(Sin asignar)","Numero":"(Sin asignar)"}]
```

The code that performs the query and the data in question is:

```
NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"user=%@&pass=%@&cod_asunto=%@", u_received, p_received, cod_received];
     NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [myRequestString UTF8String] length: [myRequestString length]];
     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

     [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
     [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
     [request setHTTPBody:myRequestData];

     NSURLResponse *response;
     NSError *error;

     NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

     NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[returnData bytes]];

     NSData *jsondata = [content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

     NSError *jsonError = nil; 


     id jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsondata options:kNilOptions error:&jsonError];

     NSMutableArray *NombreOrga = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray *NombreInstancia = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     NSMutableArray *Numero = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

     if ([jsonObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
     NSLog(@"Its an ARRAY!!.");

     NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray *)jsonObject;

     for (id item in jsonArray) {
     if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {

     NSString *aux = [(NSDictionary*)item objectForKey:@"NombreOrganismo"];   
     NSString *aux2 = [(NSDictionary*)item objectForKey:@"Numero"];
     NSString *aux3 = [(NSDictionary*)item objectForKey:@"NombreTipoInstancia"];

     if (aux) {
         [NombreOrga addObject:aux];
     }
     if (aux2) {
         [NombreInstancia addObject:aux2];
     }
     if (aux3) {
         [Numero addObject:aux3];
     }

     } else {
     NSLog(@"item %@ is not a dictionary",item);
     }

     }
     }
     else {
     NSLog(@"Its probably a DICTIONARY!.");

     }
```

It's very strange, sometimes NSLog tells me "**Its probably a DICTIONARY!**" and the value is empty and the app does not work. And sometimes NSLog tells me "**Its an ARRAY!**" and the application works correctly.

**But the data returned by the SCRIPT are always the same!**

Thank you very much everyone for your help.

Comment: Why do I get negative votes on my question? I was polite and respectful and clearly drafted my doubt ...

On the other hand, I used the search engine and I have not found the answer to my question ...

Comment: Check error in `sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:`. I think it is redundant to convert `returnData` to `NSString` before parsing. Pass `returnData` directly to `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:`. Check its error also.

Comment: Check whether u have special characters in your data,try to open the url in a browser and check

Comment: #Akbar i usually have special characters but sometimes work and sometimes not. With the same data, so i think it is not.                                                                 #vokilam, i will try ur idea, give me 2 minutes.

Comment: I pass returnData to JSONObjectWithData:options:error but the problem persists. The problem happens 1 in 10 times, but it's annoying because the application does not work.

Comment: @Eladar Use `@username` to tag someone :)

Comment: Put `NSLog(@"%@", jsonError);` after `id jsonObject = ...` to see if there's a problem converting the data to JSON... Also, I had that problem with special characters, it seems iOS doesn't support them very well, so I ended up using [SBJson](http://sbjson.org) instead

Comment: In a future i will try SBJson, thanks for the info. I think the problem is for special characters, but it has not so much logic for me because sometimes works with the same data and another times not :S im confused

Comment: I would also add an `NSLog` for the `content` string you have, to see if it highlights any special characters. The fact that the call doesn't work every 10th time also implies that it may not always be returning the same data?

Comment: The app return always the same data, i used NSLog for the content and the content is always the same. The app works fine but 1 in 10 times crash and it is annoying

Comment: I also have this error log it does not mean that:  wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003